# does not support layout file for multi-size screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have developed an xml file . The code of this file is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#257D87" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_text1"
        android:textColor="#E6E0D2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt1_dim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_text2"
        android:textColor="#E6E0D2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt2_dim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_timer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV2"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_time_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt1_dim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_timer"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_desc_text"
        android:textColor="#ED1847"
        android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt2_dim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV3"
        android:text="to go "
        android:textColor="#E6E0D2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt3_dim" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#BF9A54"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV4"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/before_campaign_btn1_dim"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/before_campaign_btn1_dim"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/before_campaign_btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#BF9A54"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_btn1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/before_campaign_btn2_dim"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/before_campaign_btn2_dim"
        android:text="@string/before_campaign_button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the output of this code is showing different output screen in different size screen . I can not understand why ? I am trying by conveting relative layout to all layout . but there is no result .

[image]

Please help me by giving your valuable advice . How can I solve this problem ? I just want the following screen . 
[image]

Comment: So what do you expect?

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ? You could for example provider different text sizes by providing size dependent dimensions (e.g. define `@dimen/before_campaign_txt1_dim` in `values-xlarge` etc - see linked article)

Comment: what value have you specified for @dimen/before_campaign_txt2_dim ,@dimen/before_campaign_txt3_dim ??

Comment: <dimen name="before_campaign_txt1_dim">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="before_campaign_txt2_dim">40dp</dimen>

Comment: try my code i update it as per your requirement

Comment: @BeginerInAndroid You need to create different `values` folder to support for different screensize and define the `dimen` values in each folder. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: I am trying your code .

Comment: @Grishu , Can you give me an example ?

Comment: ish . I have an error in picture . Now I have corrected it .Can you check it please ?

Comment: ok thn you have to change last button layout orientation from horizntal to vertical okk...

Comment: if you want to use any layout for multi-size than take linerlayout only not relative layout this layout create problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Plz Use THe Linearlayout Insted Of Relative layout try This Code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Thnkyou Foe Choosing Your Favorite Gifts!"
                android:textColor="#E6E0D2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt1_dim" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="You Will Be Reminded To Enter The giveaway When these items are avilable. "
                android:textColor="#E6E0D2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt2_dim" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/before_campaign_timer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Check The CompAndSave Giveaway Page For the latest news and updates."
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt1_dim" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/before_campaign_tV3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_timer"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ED1847"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Go To GiveAway Page"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/before_campaign_txt2_dim" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/before_campaign_btn1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_tV4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#BF9A54"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/before_campaign_btn1_dim"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/before_campaign_btn1_dim"
                    android:text="@string/before_campaign_button1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/before_campaign_btn2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/before_campaign_btn1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#BF9A54"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/before_campaign_btn2_dim"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/before_campaign_btn2_dim"
                    android:text="@string/before_campaign_button2"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

make it programatically , in the following code learn how to make it:

```
          if (displayMetrics.density == 1.0) {
            tv.setTextSize(3 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        }else if (displayMetrics.density == 1.5) {
            tv.setTextSize(6 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        }else if (displayMetrics.density == 2.0) {
            tv.setTextSize(9* getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        }else if (displayMetrics.density == 3.0) {
            tv.setTextSize(12 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        }
```

the above code detect screen resolution for the device and make text size.